# How to remove a parenthesis from a cellvalue in sql?

Tags: mysql, sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a cell value `(-4.00)`, where i want to replace the parenthesis `'(', ')'` with space or nothing at all, but it gives me error.

I tried `Replace(Replace(cellvalue, ')', ' '),'(', ' ')` but the error that I get is

> Number value '' is not recognised.

Comment: Snowflake != MySQL

Answer (score 1):

You could use [TRANSLATE](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/translate.html):

```
SELECT cellvalue, 
       TRANSLATE(cellvalue::STRING, '()', '  ') AS paranthesis_removed,
       TRY_CAST(paranthesis_removed AS NUMBER) -- if cast needed
FROM Tab
```